# Sort an ArrayList of an object using Cache

Tags: java, caching, arraylist

Any suggestion regarding below problem would be appreciated.

Present situation:
I have an ArrayList of object. We have already implemented the sorting using comparator. The object has hundreds of field. So the size of one single object in an ArrayList is not small. Going forward when the size of ArrayList increases we feel like this will create problem in sorting because of overall size of the ArrayList.

Plan:
We will load the objects in Cache.
Instead of taking ArrayList of the object as input, we are planning to take ArrayList of an id (string) as input. And when an id is being compared we are planning to get the object from cache.

Problem:
I don't want to load all the objects in cache because this cache will be used only during the sorting. So I don't want to create a cache of huge size just for this.

What I was planning to do was load only half of the objects in cache and in case anything is not present in cache load it from DB and read it as well as put it in cache (Which will replace one of the object in cache). I don't want to query the DB for a single object because this way I would be hitting DB tens of thousands of time.

I want to do bulk read from DB, but I was not able to strategize that.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain exactly what problem you are having with the code you have written to read several rows from the DB.

Comment: The problem is not reading all the rows from DB. The problem is that if we read all the data from DB, it would be loaded into memory and we think we might run into memory issues.

Comment: Your question says: "I want to do bulk read from DB, but I was not able to strategize that." You need to explain exactly what problem you are having.

Comment: You need to explain: How many records you will have. Will records ever be updated? How often do you add new records? Do the ordering rules ever change?

Answer (score 0):

You're very confused.

> The object has hundreds of field.

Irrelevant. Java uses references; that 'arraylist of object' you have is backed by an array, and each slot in that array takes about 8 bytes (depends on underlying VM details, could be 4 bytes too). These represent the location in memory, more or less, where the object lives.

> Going forward when the size of ArrayList increases

.... no, it won't. If you put 100,000 entries in this list, that's a total memory load, at least for the list itself, of at most 800,000 bytes, that's less than a megabyte. Put it this way: On modern hardware, that list alone can contain 100 million items and your system wouldn't be breaking a sweat (that'd be less than a GB of memory for the references). Now, if you have 100 million unique objects too (vs. say, adding the exact same object 100 million times, or adding null 100 million times), that object ALSO occupies memory. That could be a problem. But the list is not the relevant part.

> we feel like this will create problem in sorting because of overall size of the ArrayList.

No. When you sort an array list, you'll get ~ nlogn operations to sort it. The actual sorting infrastructure parts (moving objects around in the list) are near enough to zero cost (it's just blitting those 4 to 8 byte sequences around on a single memory page. Assuming the invocation of .compare() is cheap, even a throwaway $100 computer can sort millions of entries in fractions of seconds. Which just leaves the ~nlogn invokes of .compare(). If that's expensive, okay, you may have a problem. So, in a list of 1 million entries, you're looking at roughly 13 million invokes of your compare method.

How fast is it?

If calling .compare(a, b) (where a and b are pointers to instances of your 'hundreds of fields' objects) inspects every single one of those hundreds of fields, that could get a little tricky perhaps, but if it just checks a few of them, there's nothing to worry about here. CPUs are *FAST*. You may go: "MILLIONS? Oh my gosh!", but your CPU laughs at this job.

> We will load the objects in Cache.

This plan is bad, because of the above reasons.

> I want to do bulk read from DB

Okay, so when you started out with 'we have an arraylist of object', actually you don't have that, and you have a DB connection? Which one is it?

Either you have all your data in an arraylist, or you have your data in a DB. If it's all in an arraylist, the DB part is irrelevant. If you don't have all your data in an arraylist, your question misleads and isn't clear.

If the data is in a DB, set up proper indices and use the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your answer actually cleared few things in my mind.
So the data is in DB but we cannot use ORDER BY clause to sort them because the sorting is done using some external rules and comparing them with object fields. So we have to load the DB data into an array list and sort it.
So the real problem for sorting the array list is that we would have to load all the objects in the memory. And because we are expecting he number of object to increase the memory consumption will also increase and we want to avoid that.